# Adding buttons to a UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, iboutlet

I have setup a tableview that currently has one section, header, and two cells. For username and password, image shown below.

I would like to add a button (IBOutlet), and a label/link below this button within the Table View. What is the correct way to approach this programatically as I am not using interface builder at the moment.

Should the button be a new cell and section? Should the button be a header view and if so how do I control the height on only this header view?

[image: login table]

Comment: add button in new section not as header view but add it inside row.

Comment: Why are you using a UITableView?

Comment: @apascua there isn't much difference between me using a custom view with some uitextfields or setting the fields up as a uitableview. Easier for the later I would say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just adding another row to your table. If you add a second section with only one row the grouped tableview style will make it look like a simple button. If you need more complex styling you can of course create a custom UITableViewCell with one or more UIImageView(s).

Regarding the actually touch event I would then just stick to the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method.

If you have only one touch event for the whole UITableViewCell there isn't really a need to add a UIButton.

Answer (score 4):

you can try this inside your cell

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where index path.row == 3

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width/2,10,100,20);
    [btn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
```

sorry for naming convention

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use simple text fields instead of a table view. However, if you want the table view approach, you should use another section, and make that button a table cell.